# Questions about row canonical form of matrices

Tags: matrices

I need to find some examples to matrices in row canonical form (reduced row echelon form) which satisfies certain conditions.

1. I need to find a $3\times3$ matrix in a row canonical form $A\neq I_3$ which doesn't contain a zero column.
2. I need to find a find a $3\times3$ matrix in a row canonical form which satisfies $tr(A)=0$. I can't think about a row canonical form which has negative values in the diagonal (or only zeros).
3. I need to find two $2\times2$ matrices $A, B\neq 0$ such that $A+B$ is also a row canonical form.

I can't find example for those questions since the matrices must be in a row canonical form.

Comment: What does "canonical" mean here?

Comment: I see no definition of "canonical" or "canonical matrix" so I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I meant a matrix in a row canonical form (reduced row echelon form). I edited the question.